# How to make a DatePicker View show only date and not time

Tags: xcode4, datepicker

I have a UIDatePicker which is showing date and time by default.. but i want it in the format of year month and date only.. how to achieve this? Like how it is show in this image

[image]

Comment: This is very obvious in the documentation, did you even look?

Comment: no i didn't.. new to ios and coding.. will keep this in mind to look from next time :) thanks for the help though :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Set the datePickerMode property to UIDatePickerModeDate.

Answer (score 0):

For swift 4 and above

```
theDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePicker.Mode.date
```